# Display array values with delay on keyup

Tags: javascript

I have the following that is supposed to hide/show the array values with a delay of 3seconds:

```
function loop(s, val) {
    s.style.display = val;
    if (++i < s.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 3000);  // call myself in 3 seconds time if required
    }
};  

Autocomplete.prototype.filterCategory = function(e) {
    this.input.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
        let inputVal = this.input.value,
            patt = new RegExp(inputVal);

        for (var i = 0; i < this.categories.length; i++) {
            if(!patt.test(this.categories[i].dataset.cat)){
                //this.categories[i].style.display = "none";
                console.log('none');
                loop(this.categories[i], 'none');
            }

            else {console.log('block');
                loop(this.categories[i], 'block');
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Short HTML:

```
<div class="category" data-cat="programmer, sales, manager">
    <p class="h-text-cap">sales</p>
    <a class="btn btn__open btn__open--blue" href="">more</a>
</div>

<div class="category" data-cat="programmer, sales, manager, vendor">
    <p class="h-text-cap">sales</p>
    <a class="btn btn__open btn__open--blue" href="">more</a>
</div>

<div class="category" data-cat="programmer, sales, manager, carpenter">
    <p class="h-text-cap">capenter</p>
    <a class="btn btn__open btn__open--blue" href="">more</a>
</div>

<div class="category" data-cat="programmer, sales">
    <p class="h-text-cap">sales</p>
    <a class="btn btn__open btn__open--blue" href="">more</a>
</div>
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
function loop(s, val) {
    s[i].style.display = val;
    if (++y < s.length) {
        setTimeout(loop(s, val), 3000);  // call myself in 3 seconds time if required
    }
};  

Autocomplete.prototype.filterCategory = function(e) {
    this.input.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
        let inputVal = this.input.value,
            patt = new RegExp(inputVal),
            newA = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < this.categories.length; i++) {
            if(!patt.test(this.categories[i].dataset.cat)){
                newA.push(this.categories[i]);
                loop(newA, 'none');
            }

            else {
                loop(this.categories[i], 'block');
            }
        }

    });
}
```

**i is not defined**

by typing a job-title "programmer", I want o hide all the data-cat that don't hold that value. At the moment it works fine in terms of logic, however they all get hidden or shown in one block as opposed to individually with a 3s delay.

Comment: s[i] and then loop(this.categories,"none");

Comment: um, you call loop, but you do not pass `val` so it is undefined.

Comment: Not the best question, but methinks people are too quick with the "-1".

Comment: guys, see updated answer and "i is not defined" error